# CLI command to change env.php 'downloadable_domains'

Tags: rest-api, cli, downloadable, domain, environment-variable

Is there a CLI or rest interface that can modify the downloadable_domains section in env.php, or do I have to just manually run a sed or awk on the file during my deployment process

Thanks
(BTW, google search for "downloadable_domains" comes up with 0 results)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> /bin/magento with ...

```
  downloadable:domains:add
  downloadable:domains:remove
  downloadable:domains:show
```